# Pandas apply if condition on subsequent rows and group by

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame

```
      id  dist    ds
0      0     0     0
5      1     0     0
7      2     0     0
1      3   347   347
8      4   370    23
2      5   111  -259
9      6   115     4
3      7   222   107
4      8   898   676
11     9  2830  1932
10    10  1004 -1826
12    11  2315  1311
5244  12   556 -1759
4891  13  2111  1555
4890  14  2111     0
5268  15  4783  2672
5271  16   224 -4559
5270  17   222    -2
```

In the above, the ds column provides the difference between two subsequent rows of `dist`.  For example, the row with id 4, the ds is 23, which is nothing but 370-347.

I have to get all ids as list in the 4th column named gid that matches the following conditions:

1. If the `abs(ds)` value is greater than 0 and less than 1000, then append the id as list to the 4th column.
2. For every subsequent row check the `abs(ds)` and if it is `greater than 0 and less than 1000`, then  append the `id` to `4th column - gid`.
3. If the `abs(ds)` is `greater than 1000`, then append gid column with the id.  An example expected output is given below.

   ```
          id  dist    ds    gid
    0      0     0     0    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    5      1     0     0    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    7      2     0     0    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    1      3   347   347    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    8      4   370    23    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    2      5   111  -259    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    9      6   115     4    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    3      7   222   107    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    4      8   898   676    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    11     9  2830  1932    9
    10    10  1004 -1826    10
    12    11  2315  1311    11
    5244  12   556 -1759    12
    4891  13  2111  1555    13,14
    4890  14  2111     0    13,14
    5268  15  4783  2672    15
    5271  16   224 -4559    16
    5270  17   222    -2    17
   ```

I tried using the combination of iterrows and shift, but soon i realised I am gaining focus of only one line at a time and shift does not work.

I have tried setting a if condition and fill an array with id which I later could append to the data frame as columns, but I am not able to fill the previous rows with value from subsequent rows.

How do I get the desired output.

Comment: Why is the output at rows with index `4891` and `4890` is `13, 14`? What is the logic?

Comment: the abs(ds) is greater than 1000 and the subsequent line is 0- hence the the grouping of 13,14.  The same is true for id's zero to 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create groups fulfilling the conditions by [`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html).  Then, use [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) on the newly created groups and use [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) to broadcast the aggregated list of id's back to every row within groups, as follows:

```
m_group = df['ds'].abs().ge(1000).cumsum()      # Groups for conditions 
df['gid'] = (df.groupby(m_group)['id']
               .transform(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str).values)))
```

Output:

```
      id  dist    ds                gid
0      0     0     0  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
5      1     0     0  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
7      2     0     0  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1      3   347   347  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
8      4   370    23  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
2      5   111  -259  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
9      6   115     4  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
3      7   222   107  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
4      8   898   676  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
11     9  2830  1932                  9
10    10  1004 -1826                 10
12    11  2315  1311                 11
5244  12   556 -1759                 12
4891  13  2111  1555              13,14
4890  14  2111     0              13,14
5268  15  4783  2672                 15
5271  16   224 -4559              16,17
5270  17   222    -2              16,17
```

Comment: Many thanks indeed.  Worked like a charm and relieved me from pressure of last 3 days of iterations. I have used mutate in R, but did not know about transform.  Thank you again.